# Proof of one version of Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Show that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y > 0$ that
> $$\frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y} \le \frac{a^2}{x} + \frac{b^2}{y}$$ and
> generalize this result for $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and
> $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n > 0$

I am not sure how to solve this problems. Specifically, I tried expanding the left hand side first and reducing either $x$ or $y$ in the denominator. This couldn't work due to the $2ab$ term not being taken care of. Then I tried to move everything on one side and showing that $$\frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y} - \frac{a^2}{x} - \frac{b^2}{y} \ge 0$$. But I just don't see how to factor the left.

Edit: This is a subpart of a question where I need to prove C-S inequality. I cannot use C-S inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prove the following -

**Lemma:** Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Then, $\dfrac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy}$. (This is a special case of the **AM-GM Inequality** for two variables.)

Now, as per your work, it suffices to show that $\frac{(a+b)^2}{x+y} - \frac{a^2}{x} - \frac{b^2}{y} \leq 0$. Combining denominators and simplifying, show that this is equivalent to proving $2abxy \leq a^2y^2 + b^2x^2$.

Conclude the proof by applying the **Lemma** (Absolute values may be involved).

Comment: Why was AGM significant here? It seems I can factor $$2abxy \le a^2y^2 + b^2x^2 \iff (bx-ay)^2 \ge 0$$

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly fine. (Note that the idea of constructing the perfect square like what you did is precisely the proof for AM-GM in two variables.)

Answer (score 3):

This is the Sedrakyan's lemma, a variant of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n{a}_ib_i)^2\leq \sum_{i=1}^n{a_i^2} \sum_{i=1}^n{b_i^2}$$
Substitute $a_i \rightarrow \dfrac{a_i}{\sqrt{x_i}}$, $b_i\rightarrow \sqrt{x_i}$ then the lemma follows

Comment: May be better known as Titu's lemma, see on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titu%27s_lemma

Comment: Thanks. But I need to prove the C-S inequality from scratch. So it will be circular if I use C-S in my proof.

Comment: @IcedTea the C-S inequality can be proven by expanding both sides, then rearranging the terms into $\sum_{i\neq j} (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2\geq 0$